# adding toggle span to twitter bootstrap collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap on a new site and I need to add a plus/minus to the toggler. The section is wrapped in an EE channel entries tag to loop through career entires and create an accordion list. My accordion code is as follows:

```
{if count == "1"}
<div class="accordion" id="my_accordion">
{/if}
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <h2><a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#my_accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{count}">{title} <span class="pull-right">+</span></a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse{count}">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                {careers-summary}
                <p><a href="{page_uri}" class="btn btn-small">Learn More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{if count == total_results}
</div>
{/if}
```

The javascript I started writing that doesn't seem to want to work is as follows (see new code below):

All I'm trying to do is get the plus sign to change to a minus and vice versa when the accordion is opened/closed. The more I look at the javascript I started, even if it did actually change the text as I'd like, it would not necessarily do so when I clicked on another accordion toggler. What's the best way to get this to work and have it flexible enough to work on multiple accordion togglers?

**UPDATE** I've made some changes to the javascript and used the events Twitter Bootstrap offers. I also removed the data-parent attribute so these act like collapsible togglers and not an accordion. The new code is as follows:

```
$('.accordion').on('hide', function () {
    $('.accordion-toggle span').html('+');     
})
$('.accordion').on('show', function () {
    $('.accordion-toggle span').html('-');     
})
```

This actually changes the text but it changes the plus/minus sign for every toggler not just the toggler you clicked. I could add a custom class to each span but I'm not sure how I would then target this in the javascript without having to create a show.hide function for each toggled. That seems inefficient and there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't that line be `if ($(this).children("span").text() == '+') {` (seems to be missing 'if ('...)?

Comment: @JeromyFrench yes it should be (and was edited in file after I posted it here). I've updated the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Bootstrap `show` and `hide` events like so instead of your `click` function above:

```
$(".accordion-body").on("show",function(event){
        $('span', $(this).prev()).text('-');
});
$(".accordion-body").on("hide",function(event){
        $('span', $(this).prev()).text('+');
});
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/e9uQx/5/).

Comment: Yeah, I started to do that but I'm still having trouble making sure that the toggler text changes properly. I turned off the accordion option so you have to click the toggler to open/close it and hopefully simplify the javascript needed but it would still be nice to get this to work with the accordion behavior.

Comment: I missed the change to accordion-body. Fixed the JS and everything works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution worked for Bootstrap 3.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).find('.icon-minus-sign, .icon-plus-sign').toggleClass("icon-minus-sign icon-plus-sign");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is for an accordion where only one panel will be open at a time (for Bootstrap 3)

**1. CSS - only**

```
#accordion2 .accordion-toggle span.glyphicon.glyphicon-collapse-up:before { 
content:"\e160" /* an up type icon */
}

#accordion2 .accordion-toggle.collapsed span.glyphicon.glyphicon-collapse-up:before { 
content:"\e159" /* a down type icon */
}
```

The collapsed class needs to be set in the HTML from the outset
[JS fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3T6XF/1/)

**2. Javascript**

Using Javascript to check for the class '.collapsed' on all the links with class '.accordion-toggle':

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.accordion-toggle', function () {
        $(".accordion-toggle").each(function () {
            var iconSpan = $(this).find('.glyphicon');
            if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                $(iconSpan).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            } else {
                $(iconSpan).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JungleEditor/bCk3f/